# Wordpress API JSON return limit

Tags: json, wordpress

This is a simple question regarding Wordpress API /wp-json.  I am querying some data filtered with certain category in Wordpress.  My questions is how can I control amount of result that gets returned from my Get request...  The default returns seems to return around 11 most recent results.  Is there any way I can make it return only 1 (most recent), or like 100 posts.  What is the minimum and maximum amount I can return.  And what is the syntax for it.  This is the default request I have:

```
http://thisismywebsitewherewordpresslives.com/wp-json/posts?fiter[category_name]=Some Category Name I want to query&filter[order]=ASC
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're using v2 of the WordPress REST API, it looks like the current method of controlling the number of results returned is:

```
website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=100
```

Replace 100 with the desired count.

If you're using a custom post type, replace posts with the custom post type. Also make sure to set `'show_in_rest' => true` when configuring the custom post type.

Comment: FYI, it used to be you could use any number but now the outer limit is 100, which is terrible policy IMO. It's killing our own API's dev schedule.

Comment: This method no longer works with the latest version of the API plugin (which may soon be a part of WordPress core, and no longer a plugin). Please see my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171854/wordpress-api-json-return-limit/40731670#40731670) later in this thread.

Comment: But this still limits to 100. I want 5,000 items. Don't ask me why. Don't tell me best practice, that's what I want!

Comment: Still works like a charm on WordPress 5.0.3. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Add the filter[posts_per_page] parameter to the query to restrict the number of results returned by the API.

```
http://thisismywebsitewherewordpresslives.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=2&fiter[category_name]=Some Category Name I want to query&filter[order]=ASC
```

The above query should return only 2 results. The list of query parameters are present here https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/docs/routes/routes.md#retrieve-posts

Comment: That's what I tried, but didn't work.  It still querying all the data.

Comment: Same here, the query returns all the data

Answer (score 10):

**As another said :** (*v2*)

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10
```

But If you want to get more **next posts** : (*paged*)

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&page=2
```

**Docs :** https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation above is no longer correct. Now you'll want to use:

```
website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[posts_per_page]=100
```

Change the number to retrieve more or fewer posts. Change "posts" to your custom post type if necessary and make sure to set `'show_in_rest' => true` when registering the custom post type.

**Note:** The accepted solution is the way to go. This followup happened when these endpoints were evolving the accepted solution was broken temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the API imposes a 99 post limit return. So the max is `website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?&per_page=99`, that said it seems like you can modify to allow for additional posts. There's a discussion on that here: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2914

Answer (score 3):

You might change:

```
add_action( 'rest_YOUR_CPT_params', function($params){
    if ( isset( $params ) AND isset( $params[ 'per_page' ] ) ) {
        $params[ 'per_page' ][ 'maximum' ] = 500;
    }
    return $params;
});
```

And in fetch url add `?per_page=500`

Example: `https://domain.pl/wp-json/wp/v2/books?per_page=500`

Comment: CPT is your custom post type slug (eg. rest_books_params). I didn't test in v3.

Comment: I found now this filter in codex - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/

Comment: As you said, this is indeed correct, you only need to do "add_filter" instad of "add_action"

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one mentioned using the native filters WordPress has created for situations exactly like this.

I was able to achieve returning a desired amount of posts by default, while still allowing the `$_GET['per_page']` param to work like so:

```
/**
 * Default to all posts being returned rather than the default 10 posts per
 * page. Also, do not get in the way of the native $_GET['per_page'] setting.
 * @param {int} $newDefault  The new default amount of posts to return per paginated page
 * @return {void}
 */
function setRestApiPostsPerPage($newDefault) {
    foreach (get_post_types() as $i => $postType) {
        add_filter( "rest_{$postType}_query", function ($args, $request) {
            if (! isset($_GET['per_page'])) {
                // new default to overwrite the default 10
                $args['posts_per_page'] = $newDefault; 
            }

            return $args;
        }, 15, 2);
    }
}
```

I did find out you can't set `$args['posts_per_page'] = -1;` That results in an error being thrown *[which you can see here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.9-branch/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L329)*.

You can throw any logic within the closure/callback/filter to set the `$args['posts_per_page']` however you'd like to.

Comment: I have literally looked for hours for a solution, and eventually tried making one myself.

This is the ONLY one that worked, and is actually super efficient. You are a life saver, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The arg in V2 is "per_page" - http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

Answer (score 0):

In reference to Aaron Nusselbaum answer but corrected a few things:

- add_filter instead of add_action
- filter name must contain additional '_collection', so 'rest_YOUR_CPT_collection_params'

For example:

```
add_filter( 'rest_comment_collection_params', function($params){
    if ( isset( $params ) AND isset( $params[ 'per_page' ] ) ) {
        $params[ 'per_page' ][ 'maximum' ] = 500;
    }
    return $params;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. Paste it in your functions.php and replace with your post type and number.

```
$post_type = 'event';
add_filter("rest_{$post_type}_collection_params", function($params) {
    $params['per_page']['maximum'] = 500; // number of posts fetched
    return $params;
});
```