# Wordpress REST API V2 return all posts

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am missing the function to get ALL the posts (or CPT) by using

```
example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/country/?per_page=-1
```

or any similiar. The documentation gives as much info as this:

> per_page: Maximum number of items to be returned in result set.
>
> Default: 10

And in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171854/wordpress-api-json-return-limit/32506539#32506539) about the per_page we learn that the allowed range is 1 to 100.

In my case there will be a limited number of posts I need to get, but it will be around 200-300. Are there any workarounds to get them all other than fetching everything page per page and stitching it together?

Additional info if it does matter: I am using angular.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this instead for pagination. It returns all the posts on my site.

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=country&filter[posts_per_page]=-1`

I get returns above 100 when entered like that and can cap them at 111 etc. 
`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=country&filter[posts_per_page]=111`

For the modern WP scenarios the following function will allow you to give returns great than 99.

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'big_json_change_post_per_page', 10, 1 );
function big_json_change_post_per_page( $params ) {
    if ( isset( $params['per_page'] ) ) {
        $params['per_page']['maximum'] = 200;
    }
    return $params;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm this syntax still works? I'm trying it to no avail.

Comment: You can't [get > 100](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/) now but /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[category_name]=country&per_page=99 got me 99 returned.

Comment: does not work anymore. is there a way to get more than 100?

Comment: returns are now limited to a 100 without writing your own endpoint, otherwise paginating through them is your only option

Answer (score 13):

As of WP 4.7 you can increase the upper limit of WP REST API requests by hooking into the following filter:

[`rest_{$this->post_type}_collection_params`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_collection_params/)

This snippet should do the trick for **posts**:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'se35728943_change_post_per_page', 10, 2 );

function se35728943_change_post_per_page( $args, $request ) {
    $max = max( (int) $request->get_param( 'custom_per_page' ), 200 );
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $max;    
    return $args;
}
```

Note: you can not use standard `per_page` argument (with value more then 100) in request - `wp api` will respond with error immediately (so the hook will not help). That's in the above code wee use `custom_per_page` (you can use any another word).

Similar filter for **taxonomies**: [`rest_{$this->taxonomy}_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-taxonomy_query/)

Example:

```
add_filter( 'rest_tags_query', 'se35728943_change_terms_per_page', 2, 10 );

function se35728943_change_terms_per_page( $prepared_args, $request ){
    $max = max( 200, (int) $request->get_param( 'custom_per_page' ) );

    $prepared_args['number'] = $max;
    return $prepared_args;
}
```

Comment: Where should the code for increasing the number of posts that can be retrieved go?

Comment: @linuxfan I think the most correct place would be under plugins directory, since it's rather adjustment in logic than presentation (theme).

Comment: To make it a plugin, you could follow this simple guide, which shouldn't take longer than 10-20 minutes to read and implement: http://webcraft.tools/how-to-create-a-simple-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Thanks @jgangso !

Comment: What this does is not increasing the upper allowed limit from 100 to 200, but setting 200 as default limit (instead of 10) and allowing any higher number to be passed in `?custom_per_page`. (as it takes bigger of values 200 and the get param) Like it anyway:)

Answer (score 13):

The bellow approch worked for me. I was able to retrieve posts from a site with 79 246 posts. I used [pagination parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/) . Within a loop, from 1 to TotalPages available. See the link for doc.

```
http://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=100&page=793
```

**per_page** = 100 : means 100 posts max to be retrieved per page

**page** = 793 : means i have 793 pages with 100 posts per page. the last page had only 46 posts

A loop can then be used in a language of your choice.

Comment: What you said here had to be on comment.

Answer (score 12):

Couldn't get more than 10 with that syntax. Tried `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100` and worked up to 100.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler way that comply with protocol is to collect *all* responses, in sequence,
and perform *single* `setState()` call. As follows: (error handling omitted for readability)

```js
componentDidMount() {
    var uri = "http://your-server";
    var totalPages = 0;
    var allResults = [];

    fetch(uri)
    .then(response => {
        totalPages = response.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages');
        return response.json()})
    .then(results => {
        allResults = results;
        //console.log('Got results from server', results.length); 
        for (let i = 2; i <= totalPages ; i++){
            fetch(uri + "?page=" + i)
            .then(response => {return response.json()})
            .then( moreresults => {
                allResults = allResults.concat( moreresults ); 
            });
        }
        this.setState({responses: allResults });
    });
}
```

Comment: Answer not helpful, just copy paste of general data

Comment: Thanks for this! I needed a solution that was purely on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the X-WP-TotalPages header :)

Comment: @GnanasekaranLoganathan Its my own code.  Did not see it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

In WordPress 4.9.6, I had to use [`rest_{$this->post_type}_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/)

```
/* change amount of posts returned by REST API to 100 */
function rest_posts_per_page( $args, $request ) {
    $max = max( (int)$request->get_param( 'per_page' ), 100 );
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $max;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'rest_posts_per_page', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help, I'm using axios but is the same other

```
async multipleRequests() {
                let npage = 1;
                let url = `/sites/mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=${npage}&per_page=10`;
                let { data } = await axios.get(url);
                let tempdata = data;  

                while (tempdata.length > 0) {
                    npage++;
                    let url = `/sites/mysyte.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?page=${npage}&per_page=10`;
                    let { data } = await axios.get(url);                    
                    tempdata = data;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on doing this with other parameters, you can also add categories etc as well. EG:

```
https://www.website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=61&per_page=100
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really possible to get more then 100 posts or terms (tags, categories).
You should use `rest_{$this->post_type}_query` hook (for posts) or `rest_{$this->taxonomy}_query` hook for terms.
**But you have to know,** that it's impossible to pass a `per_page` arg in your `GET` request with more then 100 value. `WP API` will throw an error immediately (the hook will not help): `per_page must be between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive)` (with 400 http status).
To get around this problem you should pass a `per page` value in another `get` argument. And after this to trace this value in your hook.
So the code is:

### For posts

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 's976_rest_post_per_page', 2, 10 );
function s976_rest_post_per_page( array $args, WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $post_per_page = $request->get_param('s976_per_page') ? $request->get_param('s976_per_page') : 10;
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $post_per_page;
    return $args;
}
```

### For terms

```
add_filter( 'rest_category_query', 's976_rest_cats_per_page', 2, 10 );
function s976_rest_cats_per_page( array $prepared_args, WP_REST_Request $request ){
    $cats_per_page = $request->get_param('s976_per_page') ? $request->get_param('s976_per_page') : 10;
    $prepared_args['number'] = $cats_per_page;
    return $prepared_args;
}
```

Of course, for this to work, you have to pass `s976_per_page` (with any value like 500, 99999) argument in `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this 's976_per_page' bit of code successfully so many thanks,but It only returns the 'publish' tagged posts,..
How could I get this to grab ALL statuses, or, alternatively, only a set / subset of statuses
Many Thanks
JMB

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://dev.to/jackedwardlyons/how-to-get-all-wordpress-posts-from-the-wp-api-with-javascript-3j48) with javascript worked for me.

Comment: It's good practice to add the code in case the website goes down.

Comment: This is not a solution at all. The limitations still apply.

Answer (score 0):

According to documents, 100 is maximum to get. If you want more, use offsets and multiple requests. Example:

```
$i              = 0;
$check_for_more = true;

while ( $check_for_more ) {
    $offset  = $i * 100;
    $url     = network_site_url( "/wp-json/wp/v2/office?order=asc&orderby=title&per_page=100&offset={$offset}" );
    $offices = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $url ) ) );

    if ( $offices ) {
        if ( count( $offices ) < 100 ) {
            $check_for_more = false;
        }
        foreach ( $offices as $key => $office ) {
            // Do what you want
        }
    } else {
        $check_for_more = false;
    }
    $i ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this works fine (WP 5.8.1)

```
add_filter( 'rest_{YOU_CPT}_collection_params', function ( $params, WP_Post_Type $post_type ) {
    if ( '{YOU_CPT}' === $post_type->name && isset( $params['per_page'] ) ) {
        $params['per_page']['maximum'] = PHP_INT_MAX;
    }
    return $params;
}, 10, 2 );
```