# WordPress REST API - more than 10 posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I searched this issue and tried several solution with no luck.

My main route is here:
https://cnperformance.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/products?_embed

I installed the 'WP REST API filter parameter' plugin to restore filter removed when REST API moved to WordPress core.

I've tried:
https://cnperformance.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/products?_embed&?filter[per_page]=-1

and

https://cnperformance.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/products?_embed&?filter[posts_per_page]=-1

I've also tried this in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', function( $endpoints ){
    if ( ! isset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/products'] ) ) {
        return $endpoints;
    }
    unset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/products'][0]['args']['per_page']['maximum'] );
    return $endpoints;
});
```

reference here: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2316

I've set the value of posts_per_page to 100, -1, didn't make a difference. I also tried just adding the parameters '&posts_per_page=-1 without the filter query and that didn't work either. Any help or insights greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try this `https://cnperformance.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/products?_embed&per_page=100`

Comment: I would have bet money that wouldn't work but it did! could have swore I had tried that but must have been off in the formatting. thank you!!!

Comment: Please see my answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382455/1211184

Comment: @kurtg can you mark my answer as the right one or is there something unclear?

Answer (score 17):

yes, you can fetch more then the default 10 posts at once.

just add the `per_page` parameter to your request.

example: https://cnperformance.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/products/?per_page=100

while **100** is the current max limit!

more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

---

#### example how load more then 100 items at *once*

with a **for** loop and information of the **total pages amount** after your first request:

https://github.com/AndreKelling/mapple/blob/master/public/js/mapple-public.js#L46

Comment: This works like a charm. But do you have any idea if want to load more than 100 posts at once?

Comment: @KushalJayswal hi, i edited my post with an example on how you could do that with a for loop with the help of the total pages count.

Comment: Thanks @AndréKelling - any idea how this applied to the WP Rest API plugin and not Mapple?

Answer (score 2):

If per_page is not working, use filter[limit]
for example

```
https://cnperformance.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/products/?filter[limit]=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to this article if you need to get more tham 100 articles at once, into file functions.php of the current wordpress theme add next code:

```
   add_filter('rest_post_collection_params', function ($params, $post_type) {
        if (isset($params['per_page'])) {
            $params['per_page']['maximum'] = 999;//edit it as you want
        }
    
        return $params;
    }, 10, 2);
```