# Flutter: How to load all paged data with JSON

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a **wordpress** page where I publish posts.
The problem is found when **I exceed more than 10 publications in Wordpress**, the application only receives **the last 10 recent publications**.

I would like to implement that show all the posts. But I do not know how to start.

Currently **I have 15 publications** and as you can see in the image, **only the last 10 are shown**, I hope to solve this problem, thank you

This is my **JSON** code

```
    [
  {
    "id": 65,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 1 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 1</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 1...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 650,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 2 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 2</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 2...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 3 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 3</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 3...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 236,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 4 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 4</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 4...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 330,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 5 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 5</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 5...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 6 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 6</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 6...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 7 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 7</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 7...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 8 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 8</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 8...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 9 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 9</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 9...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 10 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 10</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 10...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
  {
    "id": 230,
    "date": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "date_gmt": "2014-08-24T18:56:26",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http:\/\/********\/********\/?p=1"
    },
    "modified": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-06-05T13:24:58",
    "slug": "this-url-wordpress",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "\u2018 This a test title 11 \u2019"
     },
     "content": {
       "rendered": "<p>This is a content 11</p>",
       "protected": false
     },
     "excerpt": {
       "rendered": "<p>this a excerpt 11...<\/p>\n",
       "protected": false
     },
     "author": 1,
     "featured_media": 468,
     "comment_status": "open",
     "ping_status": "open",
     "sticky": false,
     "template": "",
     "format": "standard",
     "meta": [ 
     ],
     "categories": [
      14
     ],
     "tags": [
      17,
      18
     ],
  },
]
```

This is my **Dart** code:

```
Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts() async {
  http.Response response =
  await http.get("http://*********:88/WordPress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/");
  List responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  return responseJson.map((m) => new Post.fromJson(m)).toList();
}

class Post {
    final String title;
    final String body;
    final String content;
    final String urlimagen;
    final String linkWeb;

  Post({this.title, this.body, this.content, this.urlimagen, this.linkWeb});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return new Post(
        title: json['title']['rendered'].toString(),
        body: json['excerpt']['rendered'].toString(),
        content: json['content']['rendered'].toString(),
        linkWeb: json['link'].toString(),
      );
    }
  }

  class NewsState extends State<NewsPage> {
    int _count = 0;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Noticias"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[700],
        ),
        body: new Container(
          child: new RefreshIndicator(
              child: new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                 new FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
                      future: fetchPosts(),
                      builder: (context, snapshotImg) {
                        if (snapshotImg.hasData){
                          List<Post> posts = snapshotImg.data;
                          return new Column(
                          children: posts.map((post) => new Column(
                          children: _getItems(post.title, post.body, post.content, post.linkWeb),
                          )).toList()
                        );
                      }
                      else if(snapshotImg.hasError)
                      {
                        return new Text("${snapshotImg.error}");
                      }
                        return new Center(
                          child: new Column(
                             children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(padding: new dgeInsets.all(50.0)),
                              new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
          ),
        )
      );
    }

    List<Widget> _getItems(String title, String description, String content, String url) {
      var items = <Widget>[];
      var item = new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.language, color: Colors.deepOrange[700], size: 30.0,),
              title: new Text(title),
              subtitle: new Text(description),
              onTap: ()
              {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new WebView(url: url, title: title)));
              },
            ),
                  new Divider(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange[700],
              height: 2.0,
            ),
          ],
        );
        items.add(item);
      return items;
    }

    Future<Null> _handleRefresh() async {
      await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3));

      setState(() {
        _count += 5;
      });

      return null;
    }
}
```

**A sample of the content in the app**
[image]

Comment: You dont want an "infinite" list, because it would take up "infinite" memory and crash your device.  What you are looking for is essentially lazy loading paged data... as you scroll it loads the next data set etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I changed the title of the post, thanks.

Comment: List<Post> posts = snapshotImg.data; Can you print the size of this list?

Comment: When showing, it indicates the following: https://i.gyazo.com/2926f6547de6502b84e132582dec44d4.gif?_ga=2.194330152.445686918.1528400494-1943249843.1528400494

Comment: Your JSON api returns only 10 posts with this query. Try to see if you can request more posts

Comment: Yes, only 10 posts. You need to check your request as @Tree suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is due to the Wordpress JSON API REST V2 plugin, which **limits me to 10 publications**

**More information in:** [Wordpress API JSON return limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171854/wordpress-api-json-return-limit)

I appreciate your help, thank you.