# How to sort post randomly with WP REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to display posts using the WP REST API and I want to display them randomly.

I know querying the posts the normal way with wordpress there is a orderby: rand option, which would do what I am looking for, but I can't figure it out with the REST API.

My REST API looks like this:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/fatos_random?filter[orderby]=rand&per_page=1

thanks for help

Comment: ...https://fancysquares.blog/posts/wordpress-rest-api-get-random-post-endpoint Show us your code if you need more help.

Comment: I put this code  ``add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'api', '/any', array(
        'methods'   =>  'GET',
        'callback'  =>  'get_random',
    ) );
});
function get_random() {
    return get_posts( array( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 3) );
}`` and doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not helpful. Do you get an error? Sorry I can't offer more, I don't word press.

Comment: The error i get is that "rest_invalid_param"

Comment: That is part of the error. It goes on to tell you EXACTLY what parameter is invalid...

Comment: rand is a invalid parameter

Comment: If i put orderby=title it works

Comment: OK, I'm confused then... https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters Maybe this is not `WP_Query`?

Comment: But i dont do the query, i want to do api

Comment: Sorry. I can't make heads or tails out of these word press docs. Maybe link to the source or documentation of whatever this API is? I can't even RTFM because I'm not sure what is what.

Comment: With WP_QUERY i know how to show a post randomly but i want an api that show a randomly post and i use WP REST API and i can sort a post but is always the same  post. sry for my english

Comment: @JorgeFerreira got the same problem and [this](https://felipeelia.dev/wordpress-rest-api-enable-random-order-of-posts-list/) solves it.

Answer (score 0):

wp_query accepts [a lot](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) of values for orderby, including 'rand'.

The JSON API only accepts [a few](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/): 'date,' 'relevance,' 'id,' 'include,' 'title,' and 'slug'. Or, according to [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/), one of 'author,' 'date,' 'id,' 'include,' 'modified,' 'parent,' 'relevance,' 'slug,' 'include_slugs,' 'title'.

The JSON API also has a default limit of 100 results per request, though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77339121/1374538) to an another question should increase that.

Without modifying the JSON API, to get random results, you would first need to request all results, then shuffle them, then explicitly ask for a series of them, by ID, and probably have them ordered by 'include'. But, if you have many potential results, this is far from ideal.

Modifying the JSON API is more sustainable. You could have a custom endpoint for this, similar to something that's explained [here](https://omarshishani.medium.com/how-to-use-query-parameters-in-your-wordpress-rest-api-route-endpoint-%EF%B8%8F-b325fece1de1).

The neater solution is to extend the JSON API to return random results, but, in order to avoid getting duplicates in subsequent requests, you will also need to somewhere keep track of what results have already been returned. With wp_query, you could use 'post__not_in' as the argument to pass this on. With the JSON API, the argument is 'exclude'. Or you could use some kind of server caching for this; you still have to keep track of the already returned results, somewhere.