# group by category with 5 post of each category in wordpress REST api single Request

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am not sure if this has been answered before, but vigorous googling has not led me anywhere so far.

I have a Wordpress site where I would like to display all posts, as usual, ordered by date. However, instead of setting a limit on the total number of posts displayed, I would like to set a limit on each category in a single API request. I am using WP version 5.2.

What is the best, most clean and maintainable way to achieve this?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress API JSON return limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171854/wordpress-api-json-return-limit)

Comment: No WP 4.7 or greater version have removed filters. i want group by filter

Comment: I see some people referring to the rest-filter plugin (https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter), in case it might help in your situation too.